# How to wrap a URL or Reference?

Tags: hyperref

In a LuaLaTeX book document with Koma Script I have two problems with Hyperref (which may are one):

sampel.bib

```
@online{Writ:Title,
author = {Writ, R.},
title = {Title},
date = {2005},
url = {http://www.blabliblabla.com/filefolder/folder_folder/folder/R._Schreib_AVery_-_LongTitle_That_Shoud_Have_A_Break.pdf},
urldate = {2017-08-15}}
```

linkwrap.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\addbibresource{sampelbib.bib}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,obeyspaces,spaces}{url}
\usepackage[
    breaklinks=true,    
    allbordercolors=Maroon,
    ocgcolorlinks=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    anchorcolor=Maroon, 
    citecolor=Maroon,
    filecolor=Maroon,
    linkcolor=Maroon,
    menucolor=Maroon,
    runcolor=Maroon,
    urlcolor=Maroon,
    linktoc=all
]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\-\do\_}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
Some sample text from \textcite{Writ:Title} with a link to the Chapter \ref{Too Long Reference}. \nameref{Too Long Reference} \blindtext[1]

\chapter{Another Chapter With A Too Long Text For A Nice Reference}
\label{Too Long Reference} 

\onecolumn
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When creating a PDF I get this:
[image]

What do I have to change to get wrapped the url and chapter link?

Comment: Don't use `ocgcolorlinks=true`. As the readme.pdf of hyperref says: "Main disadvantage: Links cannot be broken across lines".

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Ulrike: Thank you very much, that already is the solution!!! I didn't read the readme carefully enough!

Comment: @ATG17 : What is the purpose of the underscores in the URL?

Comment: @AlexG: the underscores are there because the real link looks like this…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ocgcolorlinks` option of the `hyperref` package prevents links from wrapping around line and page breaks. Instead, try the **`ocgx2`** package with an improved `ocgcolorlinks` implementation.

It seems though, that the `apa` style has some bug related to underscores in urls. Replacing it with `authoryear` gives the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\addbibresource{sampelbib.bib}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,hyperref]{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens,obeyspaces,spaces}{url}
\usepackage[
    breaklinks=true,    
    allbordercolors=blue,
%    ocgcolorlinks=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    anchorcolor=blue, 
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    menucolor=blue,
    runcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linktoc=all
]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\-\do\_}
\makeatother

\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
Some sample text from \textcite{Writ:Title} with a link to the Chapter \ref{Too Long Reference}. \nameref{Too Long Reference} \blindtext[1]

\chapter{Another Chapter With A Too Long Text For A Nice Reference}
\label{Too Long Reference} 

\onecolumn
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```